# H2 database with corrupted table

Tags: java, h2

We have an H2 database with what looks to be a corrupted table.  Using the H2 web console, we are able to run SELECT * queries on all the tables except one.  For this one table, TBL_TRANSACTION, we get the error result:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_TRANSACTION;
General error: "java.nio.BufferUnderflowException"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM TBL_TRANSACTION [50000-190] HY000/50000
```

When we run the H2 Recover tool, we get the following:

```
java -cp h2-1.4.190.jar org.h2.tools.Recover 
Error: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
```

The Recover tool does generate the h2.sql and the mv.txt file.  However, after all the CREATE and INSERT statements, the h2.sql ends with

```
// error: java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
```

Running RunScript against this h2.sql file does recover a part of the corrupted table, but only a very small part (only up to the part where the BufferUnderFlowException occurred.)

Questions:

1. What could have happened to cause this corruption?
2. What steps can we take to recover the data?

Thanks in advance.